# finding out the coordinates of centroid of cluster in k-means clustering

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a large amount of data. I have implemented k-means clustering on my data. It clustered the data and plot the graph having data points around centroid in the cluster.

The graph is the following:

[image]

But I want to get the exact `x` and `y` coordinates of the centroid printed so that I can calculate the distance of any new data point from the centroids so as to find out the cluster to which new data will belong.

[ids ctrs]=kmeans(A,19) 
D = dist([testpoint;ctrs]) %testpoint is 1x10 and D will be 20x20 [distance testpointID] = min(D(1,2:end)) 
I am not able to understand what [distance testpointID] = min(D(1,2:end)) actually does??Please help me!!!

Comment: Try using the **documentation**!

Comment: And **stop reposting the same question**:  [Query regarding k-means clustering in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359104/query-regarding-k-means-clustering-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

This is from the
[Matlab help for the kmeans function](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html)

```
[idx,C] = kmeans(___) % returns the k cluster centroid locations
                      % in the k-by-p matrix C.
```

This means you can call `kmeans` with two output arguments. The first one will contain the indeces to your points, the second one the centroid locations you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you've used the Matlab function, then the centroids are the second output argument. However, if you've implemented K-Means by yourself you must manually evaluate such centroids by considering their definition. For a given cluster, the centroid is nothing more then the average value between the points associated to such cluster.
If you have the assignments {point;cluster} you can easily evaluate the centroid: let's say you have a given cluster with `n` points assigned to it and these points are `a1,a2,...,an`. You can evaluate the centroid for such cluster by using:

```
centroid=(a1+a2+...+an)/n
```